# Object is used but not declared

Tags: variables, vhdl, quartus, hardware

I understand this is a fairly common question. Regardless, having gone through forums, I couldn't find a satisfactory answer as to why I'm getting the following CT error, for the given VHDL code. Can you help me please?

VHDL Code

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
entity design is
port(clk:IN std_logic;
reset:IN std_logic;
A:IN std_logic;
B:IN std_logic;
Q:OUT std_logic);
end design;

architecture behave of design is
--signal R0,R1,R2,R3,R4:std_logic;
begin
process(clk,reset)
variable R0,R1,R2,R3,R4:std_logic;
begin
if (reset='1') then
R0:='0';
R1:='0';
R2:='0';
R3:='0';
R4:='0';
elsif falling_edge(clk) then
R0:=R4;
R1:=R0 xor A;
R2:=R1 xor B;
R3:=R2;
R4:=R2 xor R3;
end if;
end process;
Q<=R4;       -- ERROR POINTED HERE
end behave;
```

Error:-

```
Error (10482): VHDL error at design.vhd(31): object "R4" is used but not declared
```

Is there a proper way of assigning variable to port, that I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`R4` is declared as a variable in the declarative region for your process. It is not visible outside of your process, so your tool is giving you the error you gave. If you move the line `Q<=R4;` inside your process, after the `end if;`, the error should go away, as the variable is still visible at this point.

With that said, I don't think your code will do what you think it will. I see that you started off using `signal` for `R1` etc. You should probably avoid using a `variable` until you have a good understanding of the differences between a signal and a variable. There are other existing questions that address this.

Comment: yup @scary_jeff, i was just testing by trial and error to see what kinda circuit i get. thank you.

Comment: @SaiKamat  What scary_jeff means is that there is no circuit here as it reduces to a constant '0' because A xor A = 0.

Answer (score 0):

R4 is a variable as you declared in your code . It cant use outside the endif statement.So  thats why you device is giving you an error massage. For removing this error you can declared R4  again outside the Q<=R4 and inside the endif statement.